# Trying to reverse a string but adds an extra character when less than 4 characters are taken as input

Tags: c

This is the code I am not able to fix it. It works fine if 5 or more characters are used but using less than 4 characters breaks it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
void main()
{
    char str[1000], rev[1000];
    int i, j, count = 0;
    printf("Enter the string :");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("\nString Before Reverse: %s", str);
    while (str[count] != '\0')
    {
        count++;
    }
    j = count-1 ;
    for (i = 0; i<count; i++)
    {
        rev[i] = str[j];
        j--;
    }
    printf("\nString After Reverse: %s", rev);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You forgot to add nul-termiation to your reversed string.

Comment: You should apply some decent indentation to your code. It makes it more readable which is especially important for beginners.

Comment: Also please get into the habit of printing *trailing* newlines. That will not only make the last output easier to distinguish when run in a console or terminal, but also write the current line to the console (as when connected to a terminal or console lines will be written at the newline).

Answer (score 1):

Your have to null terminate your rev string like:

```
rev[count] = '\0';
```

Also, please make your code more readable.

Comment: I ran the exact code and worked fine for me

Comment: @Gerhardh Alright, I'll correct my statement. Thanks.